# Does hydration level change the effect of caffeine?

Tags: caffeine

Apologies if this question does not belong here, it may be suit for the [chemistry site](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com), but it pertains to the consumption of coffee directly -> so here it is.

Does your prior level of hydration have any affect at all on how much of a "buzz" the caffeine from coffee gives you? I spoke to someone who thinks it's the case that having drunk a glass of water *before* coffee sustains the effect versus it being the first liquid introduced into your system and the rationale behind that was since your body is not in need of any liquid the effect of the caffeine is somehow prolonged.

The other side is that if there's nothing in your system and only the coffee, is it the case that its effect would be stronger since it would not be diluted with other things (e.g., water) in your system?

1. Has anyone experimented with this?
2. Is there any difference at all?
3. What are some resources for explaining the biochemistry behind this?

Answer (score -1):

Definitely. This is why you get caffeine jitters when you drink coffee on an empty stomach. Caffeine is a diuretic so it makes you more dehydrated. It is recommended to drink water before drinking caffeine, because caffeine also increases stomach acid and can cause stomach pain.